# How to fetch data from SQLite in the background with callback without Room?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to know how to fetch data from the local `SQLite` database in the background with a callback in the main thread. Say, the callback should be in a `Fragment`. And I want to avoid using the `Room` library. Currently I fetch the data in the UI thread using SQLiteHelper.

I have considered various options and understood that there is no silver bullet. For example:

- I could have used `AsyncTask`, but it should be subclassed and in case the activity is destroyed before the task is finished the data is passed to the destroyed referenced activity. As a result - a memory leak. Although, I restrict the screen rotation that lowers the chances of the Activity destruction, should I keep neglecting using `AsynkTask`?
- Another option is `IntentService`. In this way I can fetch data from SQLite in the background and use `EventBus` for a callback. However, seems like it is an overkill for such a task. The plus - easy implementation.
- `CursorLoader` with `ContentProvider` is the third option. I believe this is what I need. However, I believe the code could be verbose. I havent used these classes and after reading miles of texts, still dont know how to implement them.

What option should I choose? Please, provide me with a guided code in case you have one.

Please correct me, if I am wrong in some statements.

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated

Comment: Executor is an option, and Coroutines in Kotlin is another

Comment: There is such thing like "callback" in other (i.e. main) thread literally. But you can "ask" a thread to do some job. For example, you make a blocking queue and while(true) { xxx job = queue.take(); /* then do this particular job - process some data from SQLite put by a data fetching thread or any other job */ } in your worker thread (ok, it may be main at last). In case of Swing (not sure what UI you are talking about) you can just use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to do the same thing (to pass some job/a Runnable with the fetched data into internal "event queue" of the UI thread)

Comment: And fetch the data from SQLite in another thread(s). You can prepare a separate thread to query SQLite in the same manner (with a blocking queue of queries to be executed) or just use ExecutorService for simple cases (query one by one with newSingleThreadExecutor() to prevent race conditions) or, for example, java.util.concurrent.Phaser to orchestrate your queries in parallel.